# C# Tree into Array (with arrays as childs)

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist, jagged-arrays

well, i'm almost new to c# and i couldn't figure out how multi-leveled-arrays work in c#.

i've made a treeView with menus in it like:

---

- menu_1
- --child_1.1
- --child_1.2
- ----child_1.2.1
- ----child_1.2.2
- ----child_1.2.3
- --child_1.3
- Menu_2
- --child_2.1
- --child_2.2
- ----child_2.2.1

---

every single MenuItem should have 6 proppertys / attributes / values like this :

**Item = { ID:int , "NAME:String , POSITION:String , ACTIVE:Bool , ACTION:bool , PATH:string }**

so :

```
Menu_1 = { 1, "File", "1", true, false, "" }
child_1.1 = { 2, "Open", "1.1", true, true, "./open.exe" }
```

... and so on

so far :

i've manually set some String-Arrays ( **String[]** ) for eath menuItem and filled it with the informations.

```
String[] Item_1 = {"1", "File", "1", "1", "0", ""};
String[] Item_2 = ...

...
```

now i want to put all those String-Array inside an **ArrayList[]** and **Sort()** them using the "POSITION" value of each Item ( **Item_1[2]** )

also i want the code to dynamicly create that Array of the Item itself, reading the values from a sql table. those arrays should NOT be just String-Arrays as i did for now, cuz i want the ID to stay a int & the ACTIVE and ACTION value to stay a bool.

the final product should look like this :

```
MenuItems = ArrayList(
    item_1 = Array(Int, String, String, Bool, Bool, String)  // \
    item_2 = Array(Int, String, String, Bool, Bool, String)  //  \
    item_3 = Array(Int, String, String, Bool, Bool, String)  //  / all sortet by the 3rd value, the position )
    item_4 = Array(Int, String, String, Bool, Bool, String)  // /
    ...
    )
)
```

thanx all of you who can help me out.

Comment: *** i don't want u to write all the code :D just want some tips and maybe code snipets ^^

ideas how u think it could be processed.

Comment: So do you want to flatten the tree into one array? No more hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're on C# 2.0 or later, I'd use a generic list instead of an ArrayList and a class container rather than just arrays. Assuming you're on .NET 3.5 or later, I'd suggest using LINQ for the sorting as well.

First, make a class container for the type of the menu items:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Position {get;set;}
    public bool Active {get;set;}
    public bool Action {get;set;}
    public string Path {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can store instances of this class in a generic List:

```
var items = new List<MenuItem>();
items.Add(new MenuItem{ID="1", Name="File", Position="1", Active=true, Action=false, Path=""});
```

Then, to sort this list by position, you can use LINQ:

```
var sorted = items.OrderBy(i => i.Position);
```

Comment: thats awesome, thx a lot !!!

now i think i get the idea how c# works with that kind of "array".

( if both of u want me to vote up ur answers, u need to help me getting some reputation ^^ i think both answers r helpful, but i need to sort the elements by attributes, and also i need dynamic vars instead of defining Menu_1, or child_1_1. so @theprise, nice job ! )

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with arrays alone. Create a class containing subitems as array or as list, if you want to be flexible

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem()
    {
        SubItems = new List<MenuItem>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool Action { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public List<MenuItem> SubItems { get; private set; }
}
```

You can then add subitems like this

```
var child_1_1 = new MenuItem{ 2, "Open", "1.1", true, true, "./open.exe" };
Menu_1.SubItems.Add(child_1_1);
```